# Sticky top navbar causing scrollbar non functional

Tags: html, css

On my HTML page I have added a sticky menu but the scroll bar parallel to the navbar is not functional, I think it has gone behind the sticky navbar. Below is my HTML and CSS code and a screenshot of my page with visual explanation of problem.

**Home.html** code:

```
<div class="bot-nav contain clearfix">
 <div class="logo"><img src={{logourl}}></div>
.... //code
</div>
```

**css** code:

```
.bot-nav
{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

See the below image for a visual explanation:

[image]

Comment: What is in the .contain and .clearfix classes? Can you recreate this problem in a fiddle?

Comment: What he said. Using your current code, the problem is not reproducible in FF, Chrome or IE11. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvgKpW

Comment: On Chrome or Firefox, you can install `Web Developer` plugin & use the outline features on these elements to see which elements are causing this scrollbar.

Comment: tried to reproduce but problem not coming here `http://jsfiddle.net/o6wdbys0/12/` , but in our website `sapphireprofits.com` it is coming..site made in ionic

Comment: Did you add your html within the <body></body> node?

Comment: Have you tried it in other browsers?